# Spring: asynchronous eventing

Tags: java, spring

I've read that in Spring all events are populated synchronously by default. Means that while current event isn't processed by handler, another events are blocked.

***Question:*** How to make asynchronous events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.html). [This](http://learningviacode.blogspot.in/2012/08/publishing-events-asynchronously.html) post provides explanation.